# Spring Frame Work Understand

Tags: spring

I have developed a web application using spring framework. Now, how does a person who uses this application know that it has been developed using spring framework?

Comment: There are more possibilities to do this, i think the most fast solution will be give him your number

Answer (score 0):

If you see the log of the application and you are using the Spring MVC you are using DispatcherServlet you handle the request/response so you will see in the log.

```
DispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'springmvc'
```